# Can programmers be called code authors?

Tags: phrase-requests

Can programmers be called code authors or any other term similar in meaning to a book author?

Comment: As opposed to a mere "coder"...

Comment: Conversely, could book authors be called developers? :)

Comment: I think a very generic question one might ask would be: "Who is the author of this code?" A little less common than "Who wrote this code?" perhaps, but certainly nothing that would raise eyebrows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a programmer myself, I say "why the hell not?" — But I guess that's biased?

However, Merriam-Webster [does seem to agree with me](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/author) as it defines 'author' as:
"one that originates or creates" and cites **software authors** as an example.

So in both my opinion and the accepted definition of the word author, yes, a programmer can be considered an author.

Comment: It seems like this would only be appropriate when the author or authors being described were the primary visionaries. If I were to write out a non-trivial algorithm in pseudo code and handed it off to somebody else to implement, I would object to them being called the "code author" even if it is technically accurate.

Comment: Books often have co-authors. If I wrote pseudo code and handed it off to someone else to write the functional code, I believe they would be the author and I would be the co-author.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, but it must be used judiciously and rarely to avoid sounding pretentious.

Comment: I'm a software auteur

Comment: @mgb - LOL! You should promote yourself to software maestro.

Comment: I prefer software _stylist_ (c.f. [Punchline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punchline_(film)))

Answer (score 5):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html), a source code documentation system that supports several languages, uses the  [\author](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdauthor) tag to document who *authored* the code.

Here's a C++ example:

```
//! \class  GargleBlaster
//! \brief  Alcoholic equivalent of a mugging
//! \author Zaphod Beeblebrox
```

Comment: The same holds for [Javadoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc):  `/** @author Zaphod Beeblebrox */`

Comment: But does this refer to the author of the documentation, or of the code?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod it refers to the author of the file/class/method/function the docblock is documenting.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Always the code author(s), in my experience

Comment: @Gnawme, that is my experience as well, but I don't believe I have ever encountered the case where the author of the code and the author of the documentation metadata are different. For this case, I am starting to think it makes much more sense for the [\\@]author tag to refer to the author of the documentation, as this is the person who should be contacted about problems with the documentation.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Doxygen is _source code_ documentation; it's rare that anyone other than a developer writes it. (In some cases, you might have a junior developer documenting code after the fact, but I very much doubt that they'd put in their name as the _author_.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of poetry in Perl. Flexible syntax allows to write so.

https://gist.github.com/1610861

Yes, programmers can be called code authors.

Answer (score 0):

In Spain and other European countries (France and Portugal at least), software cannot be patented; its commercial protection is achieved through intellectual property laws, the equivalent to the anglosaxon concept of copyright. Intellectual property laws, which explicitly include software, speak of a *creator or author* of the work being protected.

So I guess yes, *author* is a good term for someone who has created a piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly used to be; "Author" is a reserved word in Cobol used in the Identification Division like this

> Author: Ben Large.

to record the name of the programmer. I haven't come across it in any other language I've used and I've never heard people referring to themselves as Software Authors but you could claim the Cobol convention as a reason for using it if you want.