# Which word can describe programmer, coder and developer in computer science?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I have seen many questions here and there about programmers, coders and developers.
Like "programmer vs coder vs developer" etc. All these words are having slightly different meanings. Can we describe them together using single word?  If yes what would that word be?

References:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516/whats-the-difference-between-programmer-and-software-engineer

http://www.skorks.com/2010/03/the-difference-between-a-developer-a-programmer-and-a-computer-scientist/

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4951/what-are-the-key-differences-between-software-engineers-and-programmers

Comment: No, and neither can anyone else.  No one really knows what the terms mean.

Comment: I think *developer* just about covers it.

Comment: Computer programmer, software engineer, computer scientist. Or maybe computer geek :-)

Comment: (AmE)  Programmer is an older term, developer is newer. "computer programmer" but "software developer".  To me, "coder" seems more heads-down, less likely to be involved in planning or customer-approval processes.

Comment: They really are just synonyms.

Comment: @HotLicks if you don't know meaning then follow references .

Comment: @john - I've been programming since 1967, and I still can't tell you what someone means by "programmer".  In fact, it gets harder and harder each year.

Comment: @HotLicks you are correct.I was looking for this for my app name .

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[What is a good, short, word to describe a software engineer?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27294)* Also related: *[Can programmers be called code authors?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54678)*; *[A word for someone who has more skill than a code monkey to be at just the next level](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30758)*; and  *[Programming vs. Coding](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165952)* among others.

Answer (score 1):

In my country we use the term an [IS expert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_system) (IS for Information Systems/Information Solutions) to cover IT professionals.

Answer (score 0):

***Coder*** is one who codes.  This could mean someone who writes "computer code", ie, who writes "programs" (leaving aside for the moment the definition of "program"), or it could simply mean someone who enters codes into some device or even just a written journal -- ie, a data entry operator.  The term had been used in both senses (and probably a few more) over the past 50 years.

***Programmer*** (in the computer and electronics arena) is someone who enters a program.  But if you adjust your digital watch you are "programming" it.  And, back when computers were "programmed" with jumper wires, the process of a technician plugging in the wires was "programming", even though the scheme for doing so was written down earlier by an engineer.

***Developer*** is someone who "develops", whatever that is.  It may imply creating a complex computer program, or a "developer" may be a person who simply plugs together pre-programmed bits and pieces to construct a web page.

Your larger companies will tend to have job descriptions for, eg, "software engineer" or "system architect" or whatnot that define the terms in the context of that business's needs, but there is no standardization of the definitions.